# How do I add some specific numbers in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

lets say

In a range A1

8cm book + 13cm ruler + 0.34cm paper
then how i sum up  8 + 13 + 0.34 inside the cell then = 21.34cm

then put the sumup in A2

——————-updates question———————

Sorry, I must make the question clearer!
8cm book + 13cm ruler + ruler version#2 +0.34cm paper

And I was wondering is it still working for the code from all master?

this problem bothers me 1 week.
hope can get the anwser!
thanks!!

Comment: If you have honestly been working on this for a week you have too much time on your hands.

Comment: @Jeeped really really appreciate your code! But I have to study the code you gave me! It looks so fancy and difficult for me! By the way I never thought that I can solve the problem with vba.. and I think it’s unbreakable to solve without vba! And I think it’s too awesome for you, you probably just took 15 min to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple regex based UDF.

```
Option Explicit

Function sumNums(str As String) As Double
    Dim n As Long
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(\-?\d*\.?\d+)"
        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                sumNums = sumNums + CDbl(cmat.Item(n))
            Next n
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Is that first pattern a typo?

Comment: Yeah, my first attempt only caught integers. I tried the second without removing the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a User Defined Function, just using String indexing:

```
Function SumNumbers(s As String) As Currency
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If InStr("-0123456789.", Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            j = i
            Do 
                i = i + 1
            Loop While InStr("0123456789.", Mid(s, i, 1))
            SumNumbers = SumNumbers + CCur(Mid(s, j, i - j))
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Put it in the Visual Basic Editor (Shift+F11) in a new Module (right-click project, choose "Insert..." and "Module").

Use the formula in your sheet, for example in cell B1:

```
=SumNumbers(A1)
```

NB: I prefer to use `Currency` and `CCur` to avoid floating point errors. It expects numbers to have at the most 4 decimals, and supports up to about 14 digits before the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is:

```
Function cal_cm(cl As Range) As Double
    Dim i%, testVal$, result$
    result = "="
    For i = 1 To Len(cl)
        testVal = cl.Characters(i, 1).Text
        If "0123456789+." Like "*" & testVal & "*" Then
            result = result & testVal
        End If
    Next i
    cal_cm = Evaluate(result)
End Function
```

test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without VBA, but with some limitations:

- It expects every number to be followed by "cm"
- It expects every number to have a space in front of it (except for the first number which may be at the very start of the string)
- You need to know what the maximum count of numbers is in the input

Assuming the input string is in cell A1, you could proceed as follows:

- Leave B1 blank
- In C1 put the formula `=IFERROR(MID($A1,1,FIND("cm",$A1,LEN(B1)+2)-1), "0")`
- Copy C1 to D1, E1, and F1
- In G1 put the formula `=VALUE(IFERROR(RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(C1," ","@",LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1," ",""))),1)),C1))`
- Copy G1 to H1, I1, and J1
- In K1 put the formula `=SUM(G1:J1)`

You would get this result. The color coding identifies each of the groups that are copies:

[image]

K1 will have the desired output.

Note that F1 (and J1) contain 0. This would get the value of a fourth value in the input if it existed.

You'll understand how to make room for more cells if your input could have 5 or more numerical values embedded in it.